# When i click the anchor tag it open new tab not new window

Tags: anchor

I just want that when i click on `<a>` tag it open new window instead of opening new tab. I already use different code but it open in new tab every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U COULD USE POPUP WINDOW--->

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.GOOGLE.com/');">Open a popup window</a>
```